# how can i copy one cell value to other cells also?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to copy the content from one cell to other cells in the same column., so I want to copy the party's name to other cells up to back colour green ,like wise

[image]

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
{
    int nextRowIndex = j + 1; // the code works up to one cell.

    var value = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].Value = value;
    nextRowIndex++;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you list your cells as code formatted text instead of using an image.

Comment: how to copy one cell content to other cell. I have one column name party's name and I want to copy the same name to other cells also. copy the name upto null space

Comment: You should add that to your question text, not just as a comment.  I recommend you edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor ==System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
 {
      int nextRowIndex = j + 1; // the code works up to one cell.  
      while (dataGridView1.Rows[nextRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
      {
          dataGridView1.Rows[nextRowIndex++].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value;
      }
}
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the code? it seems to me that this wouldn't run at all, since the first cell is yellow, not green, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Just try it. The value of a cell and it's BackColor a two different things.

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question. IMO you should still explain your answer.

Comment: I used the wrong index in the while statement (j instead of nextRowIndex).

Comment: After editing my code I try to explain: nextRowIndex is set to j+1 to adress the next row. If this BackColor of this cell is green the value read in row j is copied into the row with index nextRowIndex. At the same time nextRowIndex is incremented. The while-loop ends if a cell is found with BackColor other then green. You should keep in mind, that if the last row in your datagridView has a green cell you will make an illegal access to the next (nonexitent) row. So you must always check if nextRowIndex is valid.